# Using a hash in view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

HI ,

i am using a COnstant hash in my model User
 as

MYUSER = {
  :firstname => "First Name",
  :lastname => "LAst Name",
  :designation => "My Designation"
  }

Now in my views , i have a loop where i have all those field names (firstname,lastname,designation)

So i try to send this field name as a key in

```
    <% @userfields.sort.each do |userfield| %>
        <tr>
          <td>

         <% @userkey=userfield%>
         <%= @userkey%> # gives the exact field names
          <%= User::MYUSER[:@userkey]%> # this doesnt gives anything
           <td></tr>
     <%end%>
```

How to rectify this ?? give some suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a variable as index to a hash, you should not specify the colon, the correct syntax would be:

```
User::MYUSER[@userkey]
```

or

```
User::MYUSER[@userkey.to_sym]
```

depending on the value in @userkey.

However, you could also loop the MYUSER constant directly like this:

```
<% User::MYUSER.keys.each do |key| %>
  <tr>
    <td>Key: <%= key %></td>
    <td>Value: <%=  User::MYUSER[key] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have not specified the content of @userfields so I cannot say for sure what the problem is. But if @userfields is [:firstname, :lastname, :designation] then User::MYUSER[@userkey] should work. And if @userfields is ["firstname", "lastname", "designation"] then User::MYUSER[@userkey.to_sym] should work becuase the string values are converted to symbols. But if @userfields is ["Firstname", "Lastname", "Designation"] you would also have to lowercase the string first like this User::MYUSER[@userkey.downcase.to_sym].

Comment: @DanneManna - My @userfield values are ["f i r s t n a m e","l a s t n a m e","d e s i g n a t i o n"] . How to remove the spaces in between them and use

Comment: If you really want to use that array then this will probably work: User::MYUSER[@userkey.gsub(" ", "").to_sym]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @DanneManne's answer. But more specifically, you can iterate through records using each_pair:

`<% User::MYUSER.each_pair do |key, value| %>
  <tr>
    <td>Key: <%= key %></td>
    <td>Value: <%=  value %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>`